# is_dir folder permission Unix

Tags: php, permissions, unix

I have a simple PHP script (who.php):

```
<?php
echo `whoami`;
echo is_dir('/home/pdfs/')?'Yes':'No';
```

/home/pdfs is `user1:www` and has `770` permissions.
PHP is `wwwrun` in the group `www`.

1) if I do `sudo -u wwwrun php who.php` I get

```
wwwrun
No
```

2) If I do `sudo -u user1 php who.php` I get

```
user1
Yes
```

Why is is_dir returning FALSE in the first case?

Answer (score 1):

`wwwrun` doesn't have permissions to read `/home` and hence can't directly verify that `/home/pdfs` in fact even *exists*, much less that it is a directory.

Comment: I added r access rights but same problem. But if I add x as well, it works!